Nginx with Docker - 404 Errors for Static Assets When Using a Subdirectory in the URL
I have an application running in a Docker container with Nginx configured to serve it under a subdirectory, e.g., /customer-portal/. The backend application is unaware of this prefix and expects to be served from the root (/).
Nginx Server Block:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;

    location /customer-portal/ {
        rewrite ^/customer-portal(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://customer-portal_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect / /customer-portal/;
    }
}

The main application pages load, but all static resources (like JS and CSS files) return 404 errors. The request URLs for these resources are missing the /customer-portal/ prefix when served by Nginx.
For example: https://test.com/_next/static/css/ce20e8d724c2d451.css - 404 Not Found
However, when the application is served from the root (/), everything works fine.
What I've Tried:

Adjusted Nginx location blocks to rewrite URLs and handle static
resources.
Used try_files and alias directives to serve static
content.
Temporarily removed the rewrite directive, but this did not
resolve the issue.

Question:
How can I configure Nginx to properly serve static assets under the /customer-portal/ prefix without changing the backend application? Any suggestions on handling this URL rewriting correctly?

